# Trace of a tensor in a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, tensors

If $Z$ is a rank-2 tensor, does the following differential equation mean anything to anyone:

$\nabla^2Z+\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}tr(Z)=0$

The presence of this trace really blurs my intuition. Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Comment: What is the first term? The vector Laplacian applied to the columns of $Z$? I'm confused because the second term is scalar.